# heroku error: R10, nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

Sorry, I am new to nodejs and heroku.
I have looked through a few different questions on this site that have been answered and I have tried those, but I haven't been able to get past this issue, so I thought it must be something else in the code.

Currently, if you run it locally there is no probably, but there is a problem when trying to run it on heroku.

**Logs:**

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

**Index.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

// Set: Var
var msg = '';
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require('http');
var user_update = require('./libs/user_update.js');
var user_keypress = require('./libs/user_keypress.js');
var users = {
    '127.0.0.10':   {name: 'john doe', date: '20180625'},
};

// Background
setInterval(function(){users = user_update.move(users);}, 200);

// Run
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    if(request.url.indexOf('/keypress/') !== -1)
    {
        console.log('/keypress/');
        var temp = request.url.split('/keypress/');
        var keypress = temp[Number(temp.length) - 1];
        var user = request.connection.remoteAddress.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        if(user in users)
        {
            users[user] = user_keypress[keypress](users[user]);
        }
    }
    if(request.url.indexOf('/update/users') !== -1)
    {
        console.log('/update/users');
        msg = JSON.stringify(users);
    }
    else if(request.url.indexOf('/start/') !== -1)
    {
        var temp = request.url.split('/start/');
        var username = temp[Number(temp.length) - 1];

        var user = request.connection.remoteAddress.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        if(user in users)
        {
            delete users[user];
        }
        var d = new Date;
        var timestamp = d.getFullYear() +''+ d.getMonth() +''+ d.getDay() +''+ d.getHours() +''+ d.getMinutes();
        users[user] = {name: username, date: timestamp,};
        msg = 'connect';
    }
    else{msg = 'Sever: waiting...';}
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': false,
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': 86400,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    response.end(msg);
}).listen(3000, function () {console.log('Server running on port 3000!');});

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1');
```

The app is used as a backend for a small application I am switching to nodejs.  It is accessed through ajax from a different site and should reply back with JSON based on the users variable.

I am wondering if there is an issue with the listen() function or maybe there is something strange with the format.  Does anyone have any suggestions or answers of what to do and what might be causing this error, so I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku requires you to use listen on their own specified port.

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

This has fixed the problem and everything is working as planned.
The heroku documentation is all over the place, but I finally got it from customer service.